# Doppler effect: an understandable explanation for a mathematician

Tags: mathematical-physics

I have curiosity by

> **Question.** Can someone explain me, and to the audience too, the mathematical essence behind the so called *Doppler effect*?  Thanks in advance.

Then you have the ability to translate for example from [1], or another reference in physics, the essentials in mathematical language. I excuse this questions because is a nice topics including functions, derivatives, frecuencies, and I believe too functional equations.

Please, feel free to update this post, including tags as you precise.

**References:**

[1] Wikipedia, Doppler effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect

Comment: Typo "Refereces" ? For references on the math of Doppler effect see [here](http://lasp.colorado.edu/education/outerplanets/math/doppler.pdf).

Comment: Very thanks much, I vote up your comment, and I am waiting answers. If you want answer the questions you are welcome @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a proper reference on the issue: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/prop.2190400104/abstract

Comment: I've vote up your reference, thanks @Franky_GTH very thanks much, now and I am waiting more answers.

Comment: I work on it...

Comment: You are welcome @Franky_GHT giving a nice answer you could obtain a good score in reputation, and this is the main goal: I learn and you provide  us to this community an useful answer.

Comment: JuanLG: Sorry I gave up on that. As how I understand the paper, it seems to me there is an inherently physical non-trivial question underlying. Maybe the question would perform better in the physics division?